# Is it possible to override or augment neovim's LSP configuration via a workspace config file?

Tags: neovim, clangd, nvim-lspconfig

I am using Neovim for C++ development (currently AstroNvim, and previously used LazyVim), and like it a lot. Usually I do not have any issues with the defaults for nvim-lspconfig and mason - the standard `clangd` server downloaded by **mason** from the official LLVM release is working fine.

But when it comes to ESP32 development, the official LLVM release does not recognize the `xtensa*-*-elf` target triplet. This prevents it from properly parsing the source files and whatever else is in `compile_commands.json`, so I need to use Espressif's own **clang** release, and always have to tweak my configuration to force something like:

```lua
-- nvim-lspconfig.lua
return {
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    opts = {
      servers = {
        clangd = {},
        -- whatever other language servers you want
      },
      setup = {
        clangs = function(_, opts)
          opts.cmd = "~/.espressif/tools/esp-clang/bin/clangd"
        end
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Over time this gets really annoying, especially if I need to switch back and forth before a project is complete.

So the question is, **is there a way to override the global Neovim LSP configuration using some project-specific dotfile, which is recognized and parsed automatically when I start the editor inside the project's workspace?** Something like `.editorconfig`, but for lua-style configuration, which can "help" the lazy plugin manager configure the language servers with project-specific settings. If such mechanism exists via built-in functionality, or provided by some plugin, please also provide some hint as to how **lspconfig** settings can be overridden, specifically setting the *clangd executable path* (if it differs from the way I showed in the sample above). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible with the nvim-config-local plugin.
https://github.com/klen/nvim-config-local

Add this to the `plugins` folder:

```
return {
  "klen/nvim-config-local",
  config = function()
    require("config-local").setup({
      -- Default options (optional)

      -- Config file patterns to load (lua supported)
      config_files = { ".clangd.lua", ".nvim.lua", ".nvimrc", ".exrc" },

      -- Where the plugin keeps files data
      hashfile = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/config-local",

      autocommands_create = true, -- Create autocommands (VimEnter, DirectoryChanged)
      commands_create = true, -- Create commands (ConfigLocalSource, ConfigLocalEdit, ConfigLocalTrust, ConfigLocalIgnore)
      silent = false, -- Disable plugin messages (Config loaded/ignored)
      lookup_parents = false, -- Lookup config files in parent directories
    })
  end,
}
```

Then in your project root directory, create a file `.clangd.nvim` with this content:

```
require("lspconfig").clangd.setup({
    cmd = {
        "~/.espressif/tools/esp-clang/bin/clangd",
        "--pretty",
        "--header-insertion=iwyu",
        -- "--background-index",
        -- "--suggest-missing-includes",
        "--query-driver=/path/to/toolchain/bin/",
        "-j=40",
        "--pch-storage=memory",
        "--clang-tidy",
        "--compile-commands-dir=.",
    },
    filetypes = { "c", "cpp", "objc", "objcpp", "cuda", "proto" },
})
```

Tested with LazyVim (but not with your specific ESP32 `clangd` though):

```
$ nvim --version
NVIM v0.9.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 21.1 Vera \n \l
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I had to modify it a bit to work with the `lazy` plugin manager, but after I figured out that I first need to load the plugin, then load the config file, all worked as I wanted it to be.